# IIS + PHP Data Objects + MS SQL?

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, iis-7, pdo

We're migrating an LAOP server to Win 2k8 IIS7 MSSQL and PHP (WIMP?) at work, and I'm using the opportunity to clean up the PHP. Currently it doesn't use PDO, and I'd like to rewrite the PHP to use that instead.

Challenge is, I don't know much about MSSQL and PHP deployment on Windows. The [official MSSQL PDO object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) is experimental / depreicated and recommends [PDO-ODBC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php). Microsoft [just announced](http://blogs.msdn.com/interoperability/archive/2010/04/19/sql-server-driver-for-php-2-0-ctp-adds-php-s-pdo-style-data-access-for-sql-server.aspx) a driver supporting PDO. Is there no other PDO driver? How does SQLSRV contrast with PDO-ODBC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sqlsrv driver is a thin layer on top of Microsofts implementation of ODBC. The PDO-SQLSRV driver is just an abstraction of the sqlsrv driver. Both the sqlsrv and PDO abstraction are supported and maintained by Microsoft. If you are interested, you can read more about the sqlsrv driver here: http://blogs.msdn.com/brian_swan/archive/2010/03/08/mssql-vs-sqlsrv-what-s-the-difference-part-1.aspx.

Admittedly, I don't know much about the PDO-ODBC driver.

Hope that helps.

-Brian